# Optical Flow visualization

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I am trying to visualize the output of `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` (OpenCv v3.0.0). I am not trying to draw whole image with optical flow, only the direction arrow. The problem is, I can't get to the output as in the examples. Every 10 frames I renew the points for the calculation of the flow. The function itself

```
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(CentroidFrOld, CentroidFrNow, mc, CornersCentroidNow, feat_found, feat_errors, Size(15, 15), 2, cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.03), 0);
```

Where `CentroidFrOld` is grayscale frame, `CentroidFrNow` is grayscale frame+1, `mc` is a `vector<Point2f>` array of points and `CornersCentroidNow` is an empty array waiting to be filled with new points.

When drawing them I use simple code:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < CornersCentroidNow.size(); i++){             
    if (feat_errors[i] > MAX_ERR || feat_found[i] == 0) continue; 
    Point p0(ceil(mc[i].x), ceil(mc[i].y)); // are the points of interest (centroids of contours)
    Point p1(ceil(CornersCentroidNow[i].x), ceil(CornersCentroidNow[i].y));     
    arrowedLine(empty, p0, p1, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0, 0.2);
}
```

after this block of code. When I draw them every frame I get this output:
[image: First step]

If I update the previous frame used for `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` function

```
CentroidFrOld = CentroidFrNow.clone();
```

I get this output (the line is short and it is moving foward every 10 frames - as set to get new points)
[image: Second step]

If the previous points happen to be next points as well

```
CentroidFrOld = CentroidFrNow.clone();
mc = CornersCentroidNow;
```

I get this output (the line is short, but it is moving along with the object)
[image: Third step]

The desired output I can't achieve is

[image: Desired out]

Do I need to manually lengthen the line? Noone is doing so in similar examples of implemantation of Optical Flow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw Optical flow images from ocl::PyrLKOpticalFlow::dense()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064818/how-to-draw-optical-flow-images-from-oclpyrlkopticalflowdense)

Comment: Completely unrelated - I am not trying to draw whole image with OF and the proposed algorithm at the end of the post is basicly the same as I do, but in the newer version of Opencv, in 2013 there was version 2.3.1, completely different from that which is now

Comment: you're going to need to show  more code to troubleshoot this - in particular the actual call to the `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` function. If you are setting it up correctly, it should work to simply draw lines between points in the `prevPts` array and the `nextPts` array. I would recommend you reduce `arrowedLine` to a simpler `line` draw while debugging - those short lines may be misdrawn arrowheads.

Comment: @foundry I have edited a question

Answer (score 3):

```
void drawOptFlowMapF(const Mat& flow, Mat& cflowmap, int step, const Scalar& color) {
    for (int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step)
        for (int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
        {
            const Point2f& fxy = flow.at< Point2f>(y, x);
            line(cflowmap, Point(x, y), Point(cvRound(x + fxy.x), cvRound(y + fxy.y)),
                color);
            circle(cflowmap, Point(cvRound(x + fxy.x), cvRound(y + fxy.y)), 1, color, -1);
        }
}
void displayF(Mat flow)
{
    //extraxt x and y channels
    cv::Mat xy[2]; //X,Y
    cv::split(flow, xy);

    //calculate angle and magnitude
    cv::Mat magnitude, angle;
    cv::cartToPolar(xy[0], xy[1], magnitude, angle, true);

    //translate magnitude to range [0;1]
    double mag_max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(magnitude, 0, &mag_max);
    magnitude.convertTo(magnitude, -1, 1.0 / mag_max);

    //build hsv image
    cv::Mat _hsv[3], hsv;
    _hsv[0] = angle;
    _hsv[1] = cv::Mat::ones(angle.size(), CV_32F);
    _hsv[2] = magnitude;
    cv::merge(_hsv, 3, hsv);

    //convert to BGR and show
    cv::Mat bgr;//CV_32FC3 matrix
    cv::cvtColor(hsv, bgr, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
    cv::imshow("optical flow", bgr);
    imwrite("c://resultOfOF.jpg", bgr);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```