# Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow in OpenCV Doesn't work for me

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I follow the steps in the opencv tutorial:

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

and it doesn't work for me here.

[image: output of the code]

can anyone help me figure out why i can't get output like that

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Shorttest.mp4')

# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Create some random colors
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

# Create a mask image for drawing purposes
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]

    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: I did bump into the same issue. Q on SO and possible answer - I havent tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397740/optical-flow-visualization). If you find the answer helpfull, let me know I ll accept it

Comment: @Croolman: The link you gave is only about visualization of optical flow. Do you think the OP has problems with that in his code?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why optical flow estimations may give poor results. Considering your specific problem, i would first focus on:

1. Do you have too large displacements. This can be because of low frame-rate, or because items are moving fast, or close to the camera. Measure displacements by pixels/frame. For every pyramid level, you can only hope to detect a few pixels/frame with LK.
2. Do you have motion blur? Not to be confused with Large displacements. For large motions in the real world, items become blurred along the motion direction.
3. shadows and reflections. Part of the larger class of problems: data that fails the "brightness constancy constraint" (a point must appear the same from frame to frame, although its position is different). Look through your data and assure yourself that positions actually look the same. If using sparse flow, you can check how your feature detection module is performing on each frame. The same points should tend to pop out as good features to track.
4. Do you have Multiple motions occuring? This is when cars are moving past each other for example. Not good either.

There are approaches to deal with all those issues, but prepare yourself for an engineering project.